# wx.DirDialog and App Store Sandboxing

Tags: python, objective-c, macos, wxpython, appstore-sandbox

As I understand with a sandboxing that Apple added you can no longer write outside your sandbox, but using the NSOpenPanel you can ask the user to specify the directory and let you write there. For example, there is this wrapper to simplify things: https://github.com/leighmcculloch/AppSandboxFileAccess

But I have a python app using wx, which I need to extend to support this, but as I understand wx.DirDialog doesn't have anything like this. https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.DirDialog.html?highlight=dirdialog#wx-dirdialog

Is there some other class for this?

P.S. I'm quite new to the wx+python so maybe there is some other option like integrating those Obj-c classes and using them instead of DirDialog? Although I would like to avoid it if possible